# I want to make the wordpress page extension as .html

Tags: wordpress

I have created a html design on wordpress page.By default there is no any extension for wordpress page.Inorder to make the page extension as .html ,I have added the following code in .htaccess file and edited the permalink of that page as.html but it ended up with 404 error

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress_com/

#code added by me 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301] 
#code ends here
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress_com/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've been reading blogs and forums for about 5 hours now and can't come up with anything.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way to do this in wordpress is to use a pluin
Please try this http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-page-extension/installation/

or

http://www.introsites.co.uk/wordpress/html-on-pages-plugin.html

the later is not updated since more than 2 years